# Extract all elements from within p tag scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am using scrapy to scrap a website that has a similar structure to the following:

```
<table>
    <td>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <p>
            <strong>More Text</strong>
            <br />Another Text
        </p>
    </td>
    ...
</table>
```

I am able to scrap all the text inside the different

tags with something like this `//p//text().extract()` the problem is that this splits the elements inside the same tag in the result:

```
'text': ['Some text', 'More Text', 'Another Text']
```

And ideally I would need it like this:

```
'text': ['Some text', 'More Text Another Text']
```

Is it possible to get the result like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these cases I do the following trick:

```
text = [
    ' '.join(
        line.strip() 
        for line in p.xpath('.//text()').extract() 
        if line.strip()
    ) 
    for p in response.xpath('//p')
]
```

This will give you exactly what you want.

Comment: Works like a charm! I just had to change s.xpath to response.xpath, other than that works great.

Comment: Oh, yes, it's `response` object, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use XPath `string()` (you may need to `strip()` it later):

```
text = response.xpath('string(//p)').extract()
```